# How do I graph using cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: cylindrical-coordinates

I need to graph the curves $x^2 + y^2 = 4$, and $x^2 + y^2 = 25$ in the cylindrical coordinate system, but I don't know how. I substituted $x$ and $y$ values for their cylindrical counterparts, but I am at a loss for how to find the coordinates for the graph and how to graph it in general.

Comment: Surely these are just circles of radii 2 and 5 resp., regardless of coordinate system?

Comment: How would I label my axis though? And in the cylindrical coordinate system, how would I even plot it so that it's still a circle?

Comment: Sorry, $z$ is arbitrary, so really the cross-sections are the circles I alluded too, but each are cylinders of infinite length. Use $x,y,z$ axes as usual. Label the cylinders $r = 2$ for one, $r = 5$ for the other. $\theta$ runs through $[0,2\pi)$, $z \in (-\infty,\infty)$. My apologies for the confusion